# Relating user space actions with kernel code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers

I have an up2board with Ubuntu 18.04 and dedicated kernel so I can use this board specific hardware like i.e LEDs. I turn these LEDs using following commands:

```
$ sudo -i
$ cd /sys/class/gpio
$ echo 432 > export
$ cd gpio432
$ echo "out" > direction
$ echo 1 > value
```

Now, I would like to find out two things:

1. How a command such as `echo 1 > value` propagate from user space down to driver.
2. How to find out what driver is responsible for this LEDs support.

Comment: These could be seen as two _very_ different questions. Is the first question about how redirection in the shell works, or how the driver picks up the value from the `/sys` hierarchy?

Comment: @Kusalananda, the later - how driver gets called - starting from echo 1 > value down to driver interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very briefly:

Entries in `/sys` are not really files. This mount is of type `sysfs`, and in the kernel this corresponds to an API where other parts of the kernel can register themselves. Then when the "files" of this file system are read or written, sysfs forwards these actions to the registered modules.

The `gpio` (general purpose I/O) layer of the kernel is again an abstractions where other drivers can registers. Typically these are drivers of chips or chipsets which have GPIO registers in the chips themselves. How the GPIO pins of these chips are wired depends on the hardware.

A bit more information can be found in `Documentation/gpio/gpio.txt` etc. in the kernel source code.

As for ways to identify the driver, one way is to `ll gpio432` after you have created the gpio node and look at the symlink; it will point to the device that has the chip/chipset with the GPIO registers. Then look for the driver for that device.

Another way would be to look through `dmesg` and see if the driver produces messages when it registers the GPIO.

Possibly this information can also be accessed via `udevadm`.

Comment: As for finding a driver name, I managed to found it in a way similar to yours. However your answer lacks the information about the information flow from user space to driver itself. How can I check what function is called after *echo 1 > value*? Can I put a breakpoint, print sth to the screen or log the action in kernel code?

Comment: The control flow is dynamic, and it depends on what modules are registered, so I can't think of an easy way to check what functions are called. You can't put breakpoints in kernel code (the whole system would freeze). There are various ways to trace function executions (google "kernel trace" etc.), but I haven't tried if there are enough tracepoints to trace this particular flow. The other methods will likely be less effort than setting up tracing.